# his vs him in this sentence

Tags: personal-pronouns

I'm reading Cryptonomicon by Neal Stephenson and came across the following sentence. It's taken from chapter 69, "The General":

> It is physically impossible for him to get out of the turret. Even if
>   he could, it would just lead to **his** getting arrested.

I'm not sure but the highlighted **his** in the sentence seems incorrect to me. In my opinion it should be replaced by **him** or the "getting arrested" should be changed to "arrest". Could someone, please, explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.  *Getting arrested* is a gerund phrase that acts like a noun, that works with the verb *leading*.  Example:

> The report was stapled incorrectly, which contributed to **the boss' being angry.**

In my opinion, it's not great writing though.  It would have been simpler to say

> ... which contributed to the **boss' anger.**

In the same way with your example:

> ... it would just lead to **his arrest**.

You can also use the third person, which I think turns it into a *participle phrase* that acts like an adjective

> ... it would just lead to **him** being arrested

I wouldn't overthink it though. Sometimes a writer had a particular style that just flows from their train of thought.